# How is FIWARE different from PAS182?

Tags: fiware

We are already using PAS182 for some of our projects as the standard for building Smart City.  Our customer has asked to follow the FIWARE standards.  Just want to understand what is the difference between PAS182 and FIWARE.  Can you please help us compare the two.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**PAS182** is a defined standard for data modeling within Smart Cities - it describes the relationships between various concepts so that data from local authority X should hold to the same data model definitions as data from local authority Y.

As the [BSI web page](https://www.bsigroup.com/en-GB/smart-cities/Smart-Cities-Standards-and-Publication/PAS-182-smart-cities-data-concept-model/) states:

> The smart city concept model (SCCM) provides a framework that can normalize and classify information from many sources so that data sets can be discovered and combined to gain a better picture of the needs and behaviours of a city’s citizens (residents and businesses).

[FIWARE](https://www.fiware.org/developers/) is concerned with the interoperability of the **transfer** of context data. Specifically the current state of a system (i.e. the now) is held within a context broker and all elements surround a context broker must interact with it using a defined standard [NGSI](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.01.01_60/gs_CIM009v010101p.pdf)

Therefore there is no conflict between the two - you can base your data models on the terminology defined in **PAS182**  and create your own entities by communicating with a context broker using NGSI.